# Why does behavior of set -e in a function change when that function is called in a compound command w/ || or &&?

Tags: linux, bash

I narrowed my problem to a simple example which puzzles me.

I have tested it with GNU bash 4.2.46 on Centos and 4.3.46 on Ubuntu.

Here is a bash function that returns non-zero (error) return code when called alone but reverses its behavior when I use either && or || to chain another command. It looks like a bug to me. Can someone explain why it is behaving as such?

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
$ function TEST() {( set -e; set -o pipefail; echo OK; false; echo NOT REACHED; )}
$ type TEST
TEST is a function
TEST () 
{ 
    ( set -e;
    set -o pipefail;
    echo OK;
    false;
    echo NOT REACHED )
}
$ TEST
OK
$ echo $?
1
$ TEST || echo "NON ZERO"
OK
NOT REACHED
$ echo $?
0
$ TEST && echo "UNEXPECTED"
OK
NOT REACHED
UNEXPECTED
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: `set -e` doesn't work in `||` and `&&` expressions, among other places.  It is not a good practice to use `set -e` in scripts.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @codeforester why so? The scope of -e is for the code inside the subshell. We all have functions that we want to fail if any command within in fails.

Comment: @user327407, read the FAQ entry, which will answer the "why so?".

Comment: @user327407, ...however, to summarize: It's black-letter POSIX that `set -e` only has effect on *unchecked* exit status. The rules regarding what is and is not "unchecked" are not as clear as one would hope, and the way bash interprets them has changed -- repeatedly -- over time, making behavior extremely inconsistent across releases.

Comment: @user327407, ...so, if you want your script to behave in a way that's obvious to readers and portable across releases, implement your own error handling. Yes, this mean putting `|| return` on the end of commands inside your functions. Yes, that's ugly. Too bad.

Comment: ...summary: `set -e` is fully of inconsistent, unreliable behavior -- but that's due to specification bugs, not implementation bugs.

Comment: The `-e` option will cause a bash script to exit immediately when a command fails. But this can be disabled by adding `|| true`. 

`set -o pipefail` sets the exit code of a pipeline to that of the last command to exit with a error status (or zero if all commands of the pipeline succeeds) will explain the first two observations and consistent.  The last one with `.. && true` though somehow also disables `pipefail` and very confusing behavior.

Comment: @karakfa, eh? There are no pipelines anywhere in this question... or are you referring to behaviors not in evidence?

Comment: Is there a good on-site question/answer pair for this issue? The bash tag info page could really use a link to one for easy deduping.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what I don't understand is why the behavior changes depending on whether I chain the command or not.  To me the two are at  different levels. Subshell should stop or not regardless of the callee.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes right I read it incorrectly.  Then with `... && true` disabling `-e` option, the third case is also consistent with the spec.

Comment: @karakfa Where can I find the specs?

Comment: @user327407 https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the shell doing what it is specified to do.  Non-zero return codes in `if` statements and loops, and `||` `&&` logical operators do not trigger detection by `set -e` or traps.  This makes serious error handling more difficult than in other languages.

The root of all problems is that, in the shell, there is no difference between returning a non-zero code as a meaningful and intended status, or as the result of a command failing in an uncontrolled manner.  Furthermore the special cases the shell has will disable checking at all depths in the call stack, not just the first one, entirely hiding nested failures from `set -e` and traps (this is pure evil if you ask me).

Here is a short example that shows what I mean.

```
#!/bin/bash

nested_function()
{
returnn 0 ; # Voluntarily misspelled
}

test_function()
{
if
  [[ some_test ]]
then
  nested_function
else
  return 1
fi
}

set -e
trap 'echo Will never be called' ERR

if
  test_function
then
  echo "Test OK"
else
  echo "Test failed"
fi
```

There is an obvious bug in the first function.  This function contains nothing that disables error checking, but since it is nested inside an `if` block (and not even directly, mind you), that error is completely ignored.

You do not have that problem in, say, Java, where a return value is one thing, and an exception is another thing, and where evaluating a return value in an `if` statement will not prevent an exception at any level in the call stack from doing its job.  You have `try/catch` to handle exceptions, and there is no way to mix exceptions with return codes, they are fundamentally different things (exceptions can be used as return values, but do not trigger the exception mechanism then as when thrown).

If you want to have the same thing in shell programming, you have to build it for yourself.  It can be done using a "try" function that is used in front of all calls and keeps state for each nested call, a "throw" equivalent that allows exceptions to be thrown (not as non-zero return codes, but stored inside variables), and `trap ... ERR` to intercept non-zero return codes and be able to do things like generate a stack trace and trigger a controlled exit (e.g. deleting temporary files, releasing other resources, performing notifications).

With this approach, "exceptions" are explicitly handled failures, and non-zero return codes are bugs.  You trade a bit of performance I guess, it is not trivial to implement, and it requires a lot of discipline.  In terms of ease of debugging and the level of complexity you can build in your script without being overwhelmed when trying to trace the source of a problem, it is a game changer though.

Comment: Thanks @fred, that is a usefull answer. I plan on goind this, a wrapper function that properly deals with return codes, if that is possible (then why didn't bash do it properly!?). The trickiest part I find, is that the behavior inside the subshell is affected. Someone edited the question description and there as well I don't agree that the "subshell" thing has no emphasis on.

Comment: @user327407  Why was it not done like this?  Well...  It probably has to do with what UNIX shells were intended for, how the various options and features were added in a way to minimize breaking backward compatibility.  As for subshells, I would strongly suggest you investigate what subshells inherit from the parent, and what they do not (options, traps, functions, etc.).  You will likely have to set up a separate "layer" of error handling for each subshell (using the same approach).  Getting what you want is possible (I have it working as general, reusable code), but it is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Handling error codes is the **intended** behavior of `||` and `&&`.

`set -e` is a great practice in Bash scripting to alert you to any unwanted errors. When using it sometime to chain commands like

```
set -e
possibly_failing_command || true
echo "This is always reached"
```

in order to avoid the program stopping.

Comment: Absolutely not explaining why "NOT REACHED" gets echoed in question.